# Criminal liability for neglecting to stop a suicide in the Netherlands

Tags: criminal-law, netherlands, suicide

In The Netherlands, suppose adult person A knows that adult person B is actively planning to commit suicide. Person A does not attempt to either assist in the suicide or block it.

Person B commits suicide. For what crimes, if any, can person A be prosecuted?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: No

**Long  answer**:

If you are obligated by law to help suicidal persons, you can get prosecuted.

From [Wetboek van Strafrecht, Title XV](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0001854/2019-01-01#BoekTweede_TiteldeelXV):

> Artikel 255:
>
> Hij die opzettelijk iemand tot wiens onderhoud, verpleging of verzorging hij krachtens wet of overeenkomst verplicht is, in een hulpeloze toestand brengt of laat, wordt gestraft met gevangenisstraf van ten hoogste twee jaren of geldboete van de vierde categorie.

So assuming person A was not obligated by law to help person B; and *only knew person A would commit suicide*, he/she would not be prosecutable.

**However** if person A encouraged person B to commit suicide and/or provided the tools to commit suicide you *can* get prosecuted:

> Artikel 294:
>
> 1. Hij die opzettelijk een ander tot zelfdoding aanzet, wordt, indien de zelfdoding volgt, gestraft met een gevangenisstraf van ten hoogste drie jaren of geldboete van de vierde categorie.
> 2. Hij die opzettelijk een ander bij zelfdoding behulpzaam is of hem de middelen daartoe verschaft, wordt, indien de zelfdoding volgt, gestraft met een gevangenisstraf van ten hoogste drie jaren of geldboete van de vierde categorie. Artikel 293, tweede lid, is van overeenkomstige toepassing.